# Transactions like update, cross document in mongodb and C# driver

Tags: .net, mongodb, c#-4.0, transactions

I have to update 3 document in a transaction like manner.

Meaning, either they all pass or all fail.

I'm using mongo 3.2 though it wouldn't be a problem to upgrade to 3.4.

I tried reading about it but couldn't really find a way to solve this.

Is it even possible? Is there BKM for this?
Do I need to change my document design?

I'm doing this batch mechanism that sends tasks to nodes. Tasks are like command lines and nodes are like virtual machines.

I store a document for Job (container for multiple tasks), one for tasks and one for nodes.

When I submit a task I have to change the state of the job, the task and the node, and if any of those fail I have to rollback the others.

Ideas?

Thanks!
Gili

Comment: Provide please example of your approach which you named "transaction like manner". The question is still actual.

Answer (score 0):

> if any of those fail I have to rollback the others.

MongoDB v4.0 supports [multi-document transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions), so you are able to group the updates together into one atomic (success/rollback together) operation.

For example, using [MongoDB C# driver v2.7.0](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/getting_started/quick_tour/) you can use something similar to :

```
var taskCollection = client.GetDatabase("job").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("task");

session.StartTransaction(new TransactionOptions(
                             readConcern: ReadConcern.Snapshot,
                             writeConcern: WriteConcern.WMajority));

try
{
    taskCollection.UpdateOne(
                session,
                Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("taskId", 101),
                Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("status", "complete"));
    taskCollection.UpdateOne(
                session,
                Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("nodeId", 202),
                Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("status", "complete"));
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Caught exception during transaction, aborting: {exception.Message}.");
    session.AbortTransaction();
    throw;
}
session.CommitTransaction();
```

See also [Transactions and Retryable Writes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions-and-retryable-writes).

> Do I need to change my document design?

Depends on your application use case, if you can use an [embedded data model](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/#embedded-data-models) to merge all of the information for job/task/node into a single document then you don't need to use the multi-document transactions feature.